# How can I add a custom annotation in Micronaut for tests

Tags: micronaut

How can I add a custom annotation to be used only in test classes that use Spock in a Micronaut application? For example, @Sql, which could receive a list of SQL script paths? Even though I have defined an interface and a class that extends AbstractProcessor, it seems that the processor is not triggered.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.auto.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>auto-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

```java
package example.micronaut.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Sql {
    @AliasFor(member = "scripts")
    String[] value() default {};

    @AliasFor(member = "value")
    String[] scripts() default {};
}
```

```java
package example.micronaut.annotation;

import com.google.auto.service.AutoService;
import javax.annotation.processing.*;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import java.util.Set;

@AutoService(Processor.class)
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_17)
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("example.micronaut.annotation.Sql")
public class SqlProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    public SqlProcessor() {
        System.out.println("SqlProcessor");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnvironment) {
        annotations.forEach(annotation -> {
            roundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(annotation).forEach(element -> {
                System.out.println("Element: " + element);
            });
        });
        return true;
    }
}
```

```java
@Sql([
        "classpath:scripts/cleanup-db.sql",
        "classpath:scripts/seed-data.sql"
])
class MyTestSpec extends Specification{
}
```

As a workaround, I tried implementing Processor without inheriting from AbstractProcessor.

```java
@Singleton
public class SqlProcessor {
    public boolean process(String[] filePaths) {
        for (String filePath : filePaths) {
            System.out.println("FilePath: " + filePath);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

So I added `TestBase` class as parent class of `MyTestSpec`, and it worked, even though it wasn't the desired solution.

```java
abstract class TestBase extends Specification {
    @Inject
    SqlProcessor sqlProcessor

    def setup() {
        Sql classSqlAnnotation = specificationContext.currentSpec.getAnnotation(Sql)
        if (classSqlAnnotation != null) {
            sqlProcessor.process(classSqlAnnotation.value())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Classes above are in src/test/groovy.